# Fetch data from postgresql upon ID being entered in to input field

Tags: jquery, database, postgresql, express

```
$("#id_box").blur(function(){
      var name = $.get("/profile/:`$("#id_box").val()`");
      console.log(name);     //just to see what I get from database
    }
});
```

This is my jquery in the html form. I have an input box for user to insert ID number. I am trying to get the name live right after the ID is inputted.

```
<input id="id_box" type="number" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' placeholder="Enter id" name="id_box" autofocus />
```

This is the `<input>` in the html with the jquery.

```
app.get('/profile/:user_id', function(req, res){
  database.select('*').from('users').where({user_id})
  .then(users=> {
    if(users.length){
      res.json(users[0]);
    } else {
      res.status(400).json('Not found');
    }
  })
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error getting user'))
});
```

This is the route code in my server.js. I am using node expressjs and postgresql. I received status 500 and couldn't get the json data. Am I doing it right sending request to the server in my jquery or am I doing it right overall? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Try logging/console output for some of the data to see where it fails, use browser web console to see values sent, ...

Comment: database.select('*').from('users').where('user_id', 1)

I tested it with id 1 with this line and i managed to get the json reply. I don't know how to send it back the html page though and I am looking for solution.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery $.get call return an promise object and you have to pass the callback function to receive the data correctly.

Correct way

```
$("#id_box").blur(function(){
      var name = $.get("/profile/:`$("#id_box").val()`",function(data){
          console.log(name);
      });
   });
```

Comment: Gorgeous, thank you so much. Good to know that this is the way to receive a promise object. Now, I can read the name and display it.